# System.OutOfMemoryException - When rendering 3-5 different high-res images

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, out-of-memory

BACKGROUND:
I have an app with a page that shows several low resolution thumbnails (some are 100 x 150, others a bit larger, smaller). When the user taps the image, it takes them to another page called "ImageViewer" (storing the image name in a global string, then using that string to complete the source of the image). This page shows the FULL resolution image and has a zoom option.

PROBLEM:
When 3-5 full resolution images are rendered (these images are roughly 38 MP), even though the user taps back after viewing, the app crashes with "System.OutOfMemoryException".

I understand that these images are very large, but is there a way to "remove" them from the memory after the back button is pressed? I tried changing the image source to a 1 x 1 image when the back button is pressed, but it seems as if windows phone "remembers" the render.

Thank you!

Comment: In the OnBackKeyPress event, set the image to null. That should allow GC to release the memory.

Comment: After setting the image to null, using GC.Collect() solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling GC.Collect(), I would recommend calling the [Dispose()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.dispose%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method on the objects that represent your images. This will allow you to have more control as to when the object's memory is released and should increase the performance of your application.

Most likely the object type you are using for these images inherits from the .Net [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Bitmap%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class, which wraps around a [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Bitmap. Calling the Dispose() method will free the underlying data associated with the GDI+ Bitmap directly. By setting the associated image object to null you are already doing this, but in a round about method and not at a time of your choosing. See the documentation on the [IDisposable.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method for more information on disposing objects in .Net.